# Is there a way to rebase and squash commits on Gitlab CE UI?

Tags: gitlab, git-commit

Is there a way to `rebase` and `squash` commits on Gitlab CE UI, instead of using the interactive mode through command-line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems implemented in [issue EE 150](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/150)  to the [EE PR 1024](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/merge_requests/1024), for allowing squashing merge request (GitLab EE 8.17).
See the documentation (EE for now) "[Squash and merge](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/squash_and_merge.html)".

[image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/img/squash_mr_widget.png]

The [CE issue 4106](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/4106) advocates for that feature to migrate back to CE.

Update Feb. 2018, a year later: as [Jürgen Steinblock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98491/j%C3%BCrgen-steinblock) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841227/is-there-a-way-to-rebase-and-squash-commits-on-gitlab-ce-ui/42843530#comment84951547_42843530):

> Great news!
> It looks like this will make it into 10.8: see [issue 34591](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/34591): "Squash and merge in GitLab Libre (CE)".

---

Update June 2018: [Jürgen Steinblock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98491/j%C3%BCrgen-steinblock) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841227/is-there-a-way-to-rebase-and-squash-commits-on-gitlab-ce-ui/42843530#comment89026689_42843530):

> GitLab 11 now includes **[Squash and merge for all editions](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/06/22/gitlab-11-0-released/#squash-and-merge-in-gitlab-core-and-gitlabcom-free)**, even Core (You have to manually enable a checkbox for existing merge requests and while creating new ones)

[image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/11_0/squash-and-merge-core.png]

That will help [keeping the Git history clean](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/06/07/keeping-git-commit-history-clean/)!

---

With [GitLab 13.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/08/22/gitlab-13-3-released/#squash-commits-options) (August 2020), there is a new option which is interesting for squash commits:

> ### Squash Commits Options
>
> Squashing commits in Git is a great way to combine several commits into a single one.
> It’s great for grouping several commits, which by themselves may provide little historical value, into a single large commit before pushing upstream.
> Pushing a single commit allows for a more meaningful commit message, as well as ensuring the group of commits provides a “green” continuous integration pipeline.
>
> In GitLab 13.3 we are adding configurable defaults for squashing commits, allowing project maintainers to configure the option to suit their preferred workflow.
>
> Because changing squash configuration may introduce unwanted behavior, configuration has not been changed for new or existing projects. With 314 upvotes , this is one of the most highly requested improvements by the community and we hope it allows more users to use this powerful feature.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_3/create_source_code_configurable_defaults_for_squash_commits_option.png -- Squash Commits Options]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/squash_and_merge.html#squash-commits-options) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17613).

Comment: so the feature doesn't exist on the CE version

Comment: @Kkronic Exactly: you will see plenty of votes for trying to get that in CE in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/4106

Comment: Great news. it looks like this will make it into 10.8 https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/34591

Comment: @JürgenSteinblock Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Finally: GitLab 11 now includes `Squash and merge` for all editions, even Core (You have to manually enable a checkbox for existing merge requests and while creating new ones).

Comment: @JürgenSteinblock Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, with links to the release note.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (as of version 11.4.4) it does not appear that GitLab (any edition) supports Squash when using Rebase.  This might be due to the way Squash works as a part of the "interactive" feature of Rebase (see command "rebase -i").