# Git squash a branch that contains merge commits

Tags: git, gitlab

In our company we use feature braches for the new tasks, but because multiple people can be involved in one task most of the time the feature branches are public. Sometimes we have long running branches that can take up to few months, during this time we update the feature branch quite often from master to keep in track with the others. At the end we end up with merge request that contains tens of commits and I want to squash them, we are deleting the branch after the merge so rebase is an option too, but it is a painful and long procedure with a lot of conflicts to resolve. The easiest way is with merge  - - squash, but then the merge request is not closed automatically and doesn't keep track of the merge. I need to close it manually, to mention the commit and to delete the feature branch. 
I want to ask if someone can give me a a better solution for merging these branches?

Comment: show your efforts

Comment: This is somewhat related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841227/is-there-a-way-to-rebase-and-squash-commits-on-gitlab-ce-ui

Comment: @marcolz Thanks. Hopefully soon to see this feature in GitLab CE.